# Get Date from Timestamp not working - javascript

Tags: javascript

```
  _.each(reduced[i].data, function(timerevenueObj) {

      var timestamp = timerevenueObj[0];

       for(var j = 0; j < days.length; j++)
       {


          var current = new Date(timestamp);
          var previous = days[i];

           console.log(current);
          if (current.toDateString() === previous.toDateString()) {
            console.log("*** Same day ***");
              rev = timerevenueObj[1];
          }
          innerdata.push(timerevenueObj[1])

    //console.log(timerevenueObj);

  });
```

I am getting an invalid Date for the current variable though the timestamp is correct.

```
var date = new Date(1432051200000);
```

Comment: what is the `typeof(timestamp)` and `typeof(current)`. It needs to be an int if your passing it in as milliseconds.

Comment: Check the `typeof days[i]` also `var myDate = new Date("1432051200000");` is **!==** `var myDate = new Date(1432051200000);`